# Ambari Server fatal error

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

WARN [qtp-ambari-agent-66] nio:720 - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca

I am using ambar-server version 2.1.0 with jdk1.8. At the time of registering nodes this error start.

At the same time agent is showing error ...
Server at https://ip-xxx-xx-xx-Xx.internal:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...

Comment: tried this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12746851/Configuring2-waySSLforambariwithCAsignedcerts.pdf

But still facing same issue. Using Aws redhai machine by changing it's system-release to Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)

Answer (score 5):

Run this command on each node

```
sed -i 's/verify=platform_default/verify=disable/' /etc/python/cert-verification.cfg
```

Comment: This solutions worked for me. However, I kept on searching for a solution to keep `verify=true` and found this solution: https://access.redhat.com/articles/2039753#controlling-certificate-verification-7